# jquery click event issues

Tags: jquery, click

I'm having some issues with .click() event under Internet Explorer and Chrome.

So, I've got this menu of filters:

```
<div id="filter-checkboxes" style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="crop-checkbox" onclick="init_filter('crop');" />
    <span id="crop-span">Crop</span>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="resize-checkbox" onclick="init_filter('resize');" />
    <span id="resize-span">Resize</span>
    <br />

    [...]
</div>
```

The init_filter(filter) calls at the end another function that sends a ajax req

```
function apply(action)
{
    var apply_btn = $("#apply-filter-btn");
    var values = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        apply_btn.unbind("click");
        apply_btn.click(function(){
            switch (action)
            {
                case "crop":
                    values  =   "x=" + $("#x").val() + "&y=" + $("#y").val() +
                    "&w="   + $("#w").val() + "&h=" + $("#h").val();

                    if ($("#w").val() !== "0" && $("#h").val() !== "0")
                        apply_send_req(action, apply_btn, values);
                break;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The issue is that there is a delay before the actual request is sent.
This works great only in Firefox...
So what I'm asking is what can I do to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind this code is all inside a function, I think you should drop the document ready section. If you are calling "apply" on load, wrap the call up in the document ready statement, rather than chaining it inside a function. This may solve your problem as you may be adding to the document ready event AFTER it has fired.

```
function apply(action)
{
    var apply_btn = $("#apply-filter-btn");
    var values = null;

    apply_btn.unbind("click");
    apply_btn.click(function(){
        switch (action)
        {
            case "crop":
                values  =   "x=" + $("#x").val() + "&y=" + $("#y").val() +
                "&w="   + $("#w").val() + "&h=" + $("#h").val();

                if ($("#w").val() !== "0" && $("#h").val() !== "0")
                    apply_send_req(action, apply_btn, values);
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Removing the .ready selection did help out a bit, but the behavior is not as fast as in firefox. I mean in firefox this works instant. But hey this is not the first issue I;m having with Internet Explorer :(

Comment: @wikiz - it seems like an eternal struggle with Internet Explorer, but version 9 should be a massive improvement!

Comment: Hope so, I've managed to fix the issue finally and it had nothing to do with the .click() state ... it had something to do with the async: false option for the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, should you not be defining your `apply_btn` inside the document ready section, otherwise there's a risk it may not exist and your var will be undefined?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var apply_btn = $("#apply-filter-btn"); // <-- inside .ready()
```

Comment: The end result is the same even if i define var apply_btn inside the .ready() event. Another solution (not that great) will be to have one apply button per filter... That will probably solve the delay ... I'm not that sure, I haven't tried it since I want to minimize as much possible the amount of code

Comment: @wikiz: Are you *sure* that the end result will be the same, or are you just *assuming*?

Comment: I've just tried it with the apply_btn var inside the ready selection.